# for(UIButton *keyButton in self.view keyboardView){

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

Im trying to set up the variable keybutton to allow me to retrieve all my buttons in the keyboard view. I don't know how to write it though.
another form of this initializaiton is with an NSArray:
`for(UIButton *keyButton in self.KeyBoardButtons){`

The NSSArray (keyboardButtons) works, so how can i replace that to return the buttons in a UIView.

Comment: What? Do you need `self.view.subviews`?

Comment: I want to make the establish the keybuttons for all the buttons in the uiview keyBoardView, then im going to use that to change multiple button stats compared to which button my finger is over. Im trying to remove 1 variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

```
    for(UIButton *keyButton in keyboardView.subviews){
```

I hope this helps people and i don't get down-voted for the post, because i really couldn't find it with any searching.

Solved with trial and error.